# .Net Deserialize JSON into c# object

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I'm struggling to convert a json to an c# object.

My json is generated by an other app (in typescript) here is the structure of the object used to generate my json :

[image]

With this structure i'm able to create json like:

```
{
    EQNode: { key: "userid", value: 5}
}
```

Or more complexe :

```
{
    AndNode: [
        {
            EQNode: { key: "userid", value: 5 }
        },
        {
            LikeNode: { key: "username", value: "foo" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Or even more complexe :

```
{
    AndNode: [
        {
            EQNode: { key: "userid", value: 5 }
        },
        {
            OrNode: [
                {
                    LikeNode: { key: "username", value: "foo" }
                },
                {
                    LikeNode: { key: "email", value: "foo@bar.fr" }
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'have managed to parse my json using this model :

```
public class EQNode
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class LikeNode
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class GTNode
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class LTNode
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class OrNode
{
    [JsonProperty("EQNode")]
    public EQNode EQ { get; set; }
}

public class AndNode
{
    [JsonProperty("EQNode")]
    public EQNode EQ { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LikeNode")]
    public LikeNode LIKE { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("GTNode")]
    public GTNode GT { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LTNode")]
    public LTNode LT { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrNode")]
    public List<OrNode> OR { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AndNode")]
    public List<OrNode> And { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("AndNode")]
    public List<AndNode> And { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OrNode")]
    public List<OrNode> OR { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("EQNode")]
    public EQNode EQ { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LikeNode")]
    public LikeNode LIKE { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("GTNode")]
    public GTNode GT { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LTNode")]
    public LTNode LT { get; set; }
}
```

But this seems a little "hard coded" to me. Is there a way to have a nice / better model structure for my model ?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you've got four different node classes that all have the same structure. Couldn't that just be `UnaryNode`? (I'd also strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions for your properties.)

Comment: check my answer and take help of visual studio ..no need to go in detail of understanding structure of json , visual studio do work for you

Comment: Just so you're aware, as long as the JSON names in the attribute brackets like you have, you can name the C# classes and properties whatever you want.

Comment: In JSON names are enclosed into "", i.e. { "key": "123" }, not { key: "123" }

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer , in fact all exemple in my original post was for demonstration purpose and was not my actual code or jsons, i will update my post

Comment: To avoid confusion, i started from fresh here, sorry for double post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394775/deserialize-json-using-c-sharp-with-variable-content?noredirect=1#comment81743134_47394775

Comment: rolled back the revision which was moved to a different post

Answer (score 6):

If you have Json with you than you can generate C# class using visual studio itself.

In visual studio Find "Paste Sepcial" menu. i.e. copy you json string and click on Paste special , it will generate C# class for you.

you can follow my post : [Generate Class From JSON or XML in Visual Studio](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2015/07/introduction-below-article-is-on-one-of.html)

Comment: TY I never knew about this I always used [link]http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: How did I not know this!? :D

Comment: @IainGalloway - by attending online training of visual studio

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't knew that feature, i tested it, but it makes the same code as mine (wihthout the JsonProperty decorator and with different function name) I will update my post for more infos.

Comment: To avoid confusion, i started from fresh here, sorry for double post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394775/deserialize-json-using-c-sharp-with-variable-content?noredirect=1#comment81743134_47394775

Answer (score 1):

It would be really better if you decide on a specific JSON schema and use it in both your apps. A more detailed JSON would help me give you a better insight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will update my post

Comment: To avoid confusion, i started from fresh here, sorry for double post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394775/deserialize-json-using-c-sharp-with-variable-content?noredirect=1#comment81743134_47394775